# Extracting names from a VarCorr object in lme4 and pasting it as column names

Tags: r, string, function, character, lme4

Below I was wondering if there might be a way to extract the columns `Name` and `Groups` from `vc1` and `vc2` and respectively paste them as the column names for objects `AA`, `BB`.

For example, for `MODEL 1` (below), my expected output of `AA` will be:

```
                    plate_(Intercept) #: Name & Groups column from `vc1`
Standard deviation     1.54
Proportion of Variance 1.00
Cumulative Proportion  1.00

                   sample_(Intercept) #: Name & Groups column from `vc1`
Standard deviation     3.513
Proportion of Variance 1.000
Cumulative Proportion  1.000
```

Is this achievable in R (possibly as a function)?

```
library(lme4)

## MODEL 1:
fm1 <- lmer(diameter ~ 1 + (1|plate) + (1|sample), Penicillin)

(vc1 <- VarCorr(fm1))

AA <- summary(rePCA(fm1))

## MODEL 2:
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)

(vc2 <- VarCorr(fm2))

BB <- summary(rePCA(fm2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function :

```
return_names <- function(obj, model) {

  Map(function(x, z) {
    colnames(x$importance) <- paste(z,unique(sapply(model, colnames)), sep = '_')
    x
  }, obj, names(obj))

}

return_names(AA, vc1)
#$plate
#Importance of components:
#                       plate_(Intercept)
#Standard deviation                  1.54
#Proportion of Variance              1.00
#Cumulative Proportion               1.00

#$sample
#Importance of components:
#                       sample_(Intercept)
#Standard deviation                  3.513
#Proportion of Variance              1.000
#Cumulative Proportion               1.000

return_names(BB, vc2)
#$Subject
#Importance of components:
#                       Subject_(Intercept) Subject_Days
#Standard deviation                  0.9669      0.23088
#Proportion of Variance              0.9460      0.05395
#Cumulative Proportion               0.9460      1.00000
```

Comment: congrats on 200!

Comment: Sorry, need to use `names(obj)` in the function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ronak, why your solution fails for the following?  `library(lme4); dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/sng.csv');
fm3 <- lmer(y ~ A * B * C + (A + B | group) + (C|group), data = dat); AA <-summary(rePCA(fm3)); vc1 <- VarCorr(fm3)`

Comment: I corrected the problem. I also appreciate your comment on the question above.

Comment: What would be the column names for the above model?

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237941/follow-up-extracting-names-from-a-varcorr-object-in-lme4-and-pasting-it-as-colu) is my question!

Answer (score 0):

The `summary` of `rePCA` produces a list.  You can iterate over the names of that list, draw the (unique) relevant labels from `vc1`/`vc2`, and assign those labels as `colnames`.

Note that the data frame inside each element of `rePCA` is accessed through the `$importance` attribute.

This can be wrapped as a function:

```r
set_importance_colnames <- function(vc, pca_data) {
  for (name in names(pca_data)) {
    vc_df <- as.data.frame(vc)
    target <- vc_df[vc_df$grp == name, ]
    new_label <- unique(paste(target$grp, target$var1, sep = "_"))
    colnames(pca_data[[name]]$importance) <- new_label
  }
  return(pca_data)
}
```

Output for `AA`:

```r
set_importance_colnames(vc1, AA)

$plate
Importance of components:
                       plate_(Intercept)
Standard deviation                  1.54
Proportion of Variance              1.00
Cumulative Proportion               1.00

$sample
Importance of components:
                       sample_(Intercept)
Standard deviation                  3.513
Proportion of Variance              1.000
Cumulative Proportion               1.000
```

Output for `BB`:

```r
set_importance_colnames(vc2, BB)
$Subject
Importance of components:
                       Subject_(Intercept) Subject_Days
Standard deviation                  0.9669      0.23088
Proportion of Variance              0.9460      0.05395
Cumulative Proportion               0.9460      1.00000
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, does you function work with `BB` as well?

Comment: It does now.  Needed to add a `unique()` wrapper around `paste` - seems like it is behaving as expected now.