# Follow-up: Extracting names from a VarCorr object in lme4 and pasting it as column names

Tags: r, string, function, character, lme4

I'm following up on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64095335/7223434). Function `foo` below, takes the `Name` column of `VarCorr(fit)` output and makes them the column names for `summary(rePCA(fit))` call.

It works fine when we input `fm1`, `fm2`, but I wonder why it fails for `fm3`? Is there a fix?

```
library(lme4) 
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/sng.csv')
fm1 <- lmer(diameter ~ 1 + (1|plate) + (1|sample), Penicillin) 
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm3 <- lmer(y ~ A * B * C + (A + B | group) + (C|group), data = dat)


foo <- function(fit) {
  
  obj <- summary(rePCA(fit))
  model <- VarCorr(fit)
  
  Map(function(x, z) {
    colnames(x$importance) <- paste(z, unique(sapply(model, colnames)), sep = '_')
    x
  }, obj, names(obj))
}

#EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(fm1) ###     OK !
foo(fm2) ###     OK !
foo(fm3) ###     :-( Error in dimnames(x) <- dn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function fails when length of `obj` and `model` is different. Here is a hack to make it work for `fm3`.

```
foo <- function(fit) {
  
  obj <- summary(rePCA(fit))
  model <- VarCorr(fit)
  if(length(obj) == length(model)) {
   obj <- Map(function(x, z) {
    colnames(x$importance) <- paste(z, unique(sapply(model, colnames)), sep = '_')
    x
  }, obj, names(obj))
  }
  else if(length(obj) == 1) {
    colnames(obj[[1]]$importance) <- unlist(mapply(paste, names(model), sapply(model, colnames), MoreArgs = list(sep = '_')))
  }
  return(obj)
}
```

This returns the following output :

```
foo(fm1) 

#$plate
#Importance of components:
#                       plate_(Intercept)
#Standard deviation                  1.54
#Proportion of Variance              1.00
#Cumulative Proportion               1.00

#$sample
#Importance of components:
#                       sample_(Intercept)
#Standard deviation                   3.51
#Proportion of Variance               1.00
#Cumulative Proportion                1.00

foo(fm2) 
#$Subject
#Importance of components:
#                       Subject_(Intercept) Subject_Days
#Standard deviation                   0.967       0.2309
#Proportion of Variance               0.946       0.0539
#Cumulative Proportion                0.946       1.0000

foo(fm3) 
#$group
#Importance of components:
#                       group_(Intercept) group_A group_B group.1_(Intercept) group.1_C
#Standard deviation                 1.418   1.291  0.5129              0.4542 0.0000497
#Proportion of Variance             0.485   0.402  0.0634              0.0498 0.0000000
#Cumulative Proportion              0.485   0.887  0.9502              1.0000 1.0000000
```

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes, the function fails when length of `model` and `obj` differs. See updated answer for a hack.

Comment: Ronak, it seems your hack fails in the following case, is there a fix? `library(lme4); d <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/3.csv'); fm4 <- lmer(math~year+(year|schoolid/childid), data = d); foo(fm4)`

Comment: Hmm...I am not sure if this will have any impact on other functions but for `fm4` it will work by changing the line in `Map` to `colnames(x$importance) <- paste(z, unique(c(sapply(model, colnames))), sep = '_')` @rnorouzian

Comment: Ah! you new solution fails for the following model: `fm5 <- lmer(math~year+(1|childid)+(year|schoolid), data = d)`

Comment: Yes, I guess there isn't a general solution which will work for every case. It depends on how complex your model is. The best you can do is debug and add additional condition when you discover such edge cases.

Comment: Ah! So, what do you suggest for the following model: `fm5 <- lmer(math~year+(1|childid)+(year|schoolid), data = d)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the column names from 'fit@cnms', which saves you the trouble of using 'VarCorr'. The devil seems to be the case of `fm1` which gives a list output and we may want to coerce `as.data.frame`. Then we may just use `` `colnames<-` `` and no `Map` battles are needed.

```
foo2 <- function(fit) {
  obj <- summary(rePCA(fit))
  obj <- as.data.frame(lapply(obj, `[`, "importance"))
  `colnames<-`(obj, paste(names(fit@cnms), unlist(fit@cnms), sep="_"))
}

foo2(fm1)
#                        plate_(Intercept) sample_(Intercept)
# Standard deviation              1.539676           3.512519
# Proportion of Variance          1.000000           1.000000
# Cumulative Proportion           1.000000           1.000000

foo2(fm2)
#                        Subject_(Intercept) Subject_Days
# Standard deviation                0.966868    0.2308798
# Proportion of Variance            0.946050    0.0539500
# Cumulative Proportion             0.946050    1.0000000

foo2(fm3)
#                        group_(Intercept)  group_A   group_B group_(Intercept)    group_C
# Standard deviation              1.385987 1.322335 0.5128262         0.4547251 0.08892506
# Proportion of Variance          0.463190 0.421630 0.0634100         0.0498600 0.00191000
# Cumulative Proportion           0.463190 0.884820 0.9482300         0.9980900 1.00000000
```

Another advantage I find is that the numbers come out unrounded. You could build in a `round`ing in the function or do that afterwards:

```
round(foo2(fm1), 2)
#                        plate_(Intercept) sample_(Intercept)
# Standard deviation                  1.54               3.51
# Proportion of Variance              1.00               1.00
# Cumulative Proportion               1.00               1.00
```

Comment: This looks great. But the OP correctly wants the second 'group' to be distinguished from the first mention of 'group'. In VarCorr(), the second 'group' is denoted 'group.1'.

Comment: I also like your approach, but we need to have two different `group` in the output of `fm3`: `group` and `group.1`.