# Find duplicated values in a nested dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

In my data.frame below, I was wondering if there is any `childid` that has more than 1 instance of the same value of `grade`.

I'm not sure if my code is correct, though?

```
library(tidyverse)

dd <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/3.csv')

dd %>% distinct(childid, grade) %>% 
  count(grade) %>% filter(n>1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first `count` before taking `distinct`. Try :

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>%
  count(childid, grade) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  distinct(childid)
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak, waiting to accept, did you see my question on your solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64238199/7223434)? (scroll down see the comment section)